# Playing sound by keypress using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm super new to web development, and I'm trying to get this simple example of an online drumkit working. The website loads fine, but when I press a key nothing happens. I know this is a very silly question, but I am a bit stumped. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Simple Drumkit!</h2>
<p>C = Kick, A = Crash, Z and X = Snare!</p>

<script>
const sounds = {
  'KeyZ': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/snare1.ogg',
  'KeyX': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/snare1.ogg',
  'KeyA': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/crash1.ogg',
  'KeyC': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/kik.ogg'
}

const play = sound => {
  console.log("playing",sound)
  var audio = new Audio(sound);
  audio.play();
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) { console.log(e.code)
  if (sounds[e.code]) {
    console.log("clicking",e.code)
    document.getElementById(e.code).click()
  }  
})
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I would use **function** and pass values and its works perfectly.

I am calling the function when the user presses the key and then that specific function plays sound. It has little *latency* in playback because of external links maybe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Simple Drumkit!</h2>
<p>C = Kick, A = Crash, Z and X = Snare!</p>

<script>
    
const sounds = {
  'KeyZ': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/snare1.ogg',
  'KeyX': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/snare1.ogg',
  'KeyA': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/crash1.ogg',
  'KeyC': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/kik.ogg'
}

//Changed into function
function playSound(sound) {
  console.log("playing",sound)
  var audio = new Audio(sound);
  audio.play();
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) { console.log(e.code)
  if (sounds[e.code]) {
    console.log("clicking",e.code);

    // calling function and passing sounds[e.code] which is address as arguments
    playSound(sounds[e.code]);
  }  
})
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahhhh that makes more sense actually, thank you so much!